# Laravel belongsTo по нескольким ключам

Tags: laravel

У меня есть 2 таблицы:
rigs с колонками id nme GPU_id platform_id. ...
и parts с колонками id name message ...

и мне нужно в модели Rig определить отношение messages, чтобы я мог в нём получить message из таблицы parts по GPU_id, platform_id ...

Как это сделать?

Я нашел на просторах интернета такой пакет: https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships
Но у меня он не работает.

```
    class Rig extends Model 
{
 use \Awobaz\Compoships\Compoships;

// Не работает 
 public function messages() 
{ 
return $this 
->belongsTo(Part::class, ['GPU_id', 'platform_id'], ['id', 'id']); 
} 
 
// Работает 
 public function messages() 
{ 
return $this 
->belongsTo(Part::class, ['GPU_id'], ['id']); 
}
}class Rig extends Model 
{
 use \Awobaz\Compoships\Compoships;

// Не работает 
 public function messages() 
{ 
return $this 
->belongsTo(Part::class, ['GPU_id', 'platform_id'], ['id', 'id']); 
} 
 
// Работает 
 public function messages() 
{ 
return $this 
->belongsTo(Part::class, ['GPU_id'], ['id']); 
}
}
```

Сори за оформление, пишу с телефона, ТК у стековерфлоу опять сломалась авторизация через ВК)

Comment: Не понятно у вас таблица rigs связана с таблицей parts через 2 поля это вообще как? О-о

Comment: В gpu id - id таблицы parts, plaform id - тоже id таблицы part. Ну вот бывают такие ситуации, когда никак иначе

Comment: Честно говоря, я не представляю подобную архитектуру бд. Ну попробуйте объединить по 1 полю, не очевидно зачем по второму пытаться объединить. Вам же нужна фактически "связь" между таблицами, потому этой связью может выступить как первое так и второе поле. Потому кмк можно использовать обычный $this->belongsTo(Parts::class, 'foreign_key', 'owner_key');

Comment: Есть комплектующие для ПК parts: gpu, cpu, ram и ТД . Есть сам ПК rig: gpu_id, cpu_id, ram_id и ТД. Вообще у меня игра про майнинг

Comment: У меня определены отношения: gpu, cpu, ram. То есть я могу с лёгкостью получать установленные в ПК(Риге) комплектующие

Comment: Но тут мне нужно получить message всех комплектующих, установленных в риг сразу. То есть select massage from parts where id in GPU_id, cpu_id, ram_id и тл

Comment: Вы не правильно спроектировали БД тогда. Вам в идеале нужно несколько смежных таблиц(rig->gpu, rig->cpu, rig->ram).

Comment: Мне не нужно несколько смежных таблиц. Тем более мне придется переписывать большую часть кода. 9ачем мне 6 дополнительных таблиц(6 видов комплектующих), если у меня итак все удобно работает? За исключением того что я спрашиваю. Но и это можно решить просто написав 6 отношений и объединив их одним ацессором

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось решить проблему с помощью whereIn и accessor вместо relationship, но так в принципе тоже сойдёт)

```
public function getBreakdownsAttribute() { 
 return Having::class::
whereIn('id', [ 
 $this->GPU_id, 
 $this->platform_id, 
 $this->RAM_id, 
 $this->PSU_id, 
 $this->case_id 
 ])->get(); 
 }
```